# How to initialize the first characters of each word in a textArea in java

Tags: java

I'm working on a mini word-Processor in Java, and I want to create a button that capitalizes only the first characters of each word in my textArea. Could you please help?

Comment: get the text as string, take every word and take the first character as substring and capitalize it

Comment: what have you tried, and what result did you get? Please review [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"` this property in your `EditText` and `TextView` for first characters as Capital latter.

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
String sentence = "hello world how are you 9";
//split your String with a space
String[] spl = sentence.split(" ");
String result = "";
//loop throw your array and capitalize the first letter
for(String s : spl){
    /*the idea here is to get the 1st char of your word and capitalize it
    then concatenate it with the rest of your word*/
    result += s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1) + " ";
}
System.out.println(result);
```

then you can put the result in your `textArea`

This will return :

```
Hello World How Are You 9
```

Comment: i need that the change appears in the textArea

Comment: what textArea? Swing or what @SafaeMostarhfir?